# Magento - Varien Grid - Totaling entire collection

Tags: magento, grid

I have created a custom product grid using the varien grid functionality and am using it as an order form.  Basically, there is a Product Name, Product Price, and an input field for the user to enter the amount of a product they would like.

There are thousands of products, and I need to give a running subtotal of what the user has selected.

The closest I've gotten is as adding the following to Grid.php...

```
   protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection()->load();
    $total = 0;
    if ($collection) {
            foreach($collection as $item)  {
                    $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
                    $itemQty = $item->getQty();
                    $total = $total + ($itemPrice * $itemQty);
            }
       echo $total;
    }
}
```

However, the results are affected by the current limit, and therefore only totals the current page.

Is there a way around this, or a better way to get the running total of the two columns?

Thanks in advance, I've been stuck on this for days!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to clear the collection complements, and set for the first page a big limit

```php
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear();
$_productCollection->setPage(1,99999);
```